# Turn a balanced realization state space model to stable - Eigenvalues

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

After I have turn my ordinary state space model to a balanced state space model by using Balanced Realization. The balanced state space model does not have all eigenvalues negative. The model is still stable if I look at the simulation of the model.

But is there a way to turn a balanced state space model stable according to the eigenvalues?

Comment: Doing simulations does not ensure that it is stable. For example the time scale of the unstable mode might be much larger then the simulated time. Or the input and/or initial conditions did not excite the unstable mode.

Comment: So is there any way to turn a balanced model to a stable model?

Comment: You can just ignore the unstable modes by reducing the state dimension, however by definition this will give a system which has different dynamics than the original system.

Comment: Ok. I assume that there is nothing to do about balanced state space models. If you wonder what I'm doing, I use Ho-Kalman-Kung/Eigensystem Realization algorithm to estimate a state space model from only output markov-parameter(impulse) data. I had some problems when I wanted to find the solution to Algebraic Riccati Equation because solution $X$ from ARE-equation need to be $X >= 0$.